# Mongodb Update Query returning ambiguous count

Tags: mongodb

Based out of this example [Mongo Pull](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/), we have the below collection

```
{
   _id: 1,
   results: [
      { item: "A", score: 5 },
      { item: "B", score: 8, comment: "Strongly agree" }
   ]
}
{
   _id: 2,
   results: [
      { item: "C", score: 8, comment: "Strongly agree" },
      { item: "B", score: 4 }
   ]
}
```

The following query removes a matching element from array.

```
db.survey.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { results: { score: 8 , item: "B" } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

The query works perfectly fine. But I am not sure on the below

**Qn 1**. Why is the above query returning **"Updated 2 existing record(s)"** always even if there were no matching documents

Alternatively I provided the update with **query** parameter - notice how query needs elemMatch and $pull doesnt require elemMatch

```
db.survey.update(
  {results: { $elemMatch : { score: 8 , item: "B" } } },
  { $pull: { results: { score: 8 , item: "B" } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

This return **Updated 0 record** as expected.

**Qn 2**. Is it really necessary to provide a query parameter when doing the update pull operation. Isnt it implicity understood, that only look for $pull criterion documents without the need to explicitly setting in the udpate query parameter.

**Qn 3** is there a better way of writing this query from full collection scan

Answer (score 0):

**Qn 1 and Qn 2**:

You only have to specify the query parameter if you know exactly which document you want to change. Update takes (atleast) two parameters: **a query document, which locates documents to update, and a modifier document, which describes the changes to make to the documents found.**. `$pull` is a modifier. You can update specific fields in a document using atomic update modifiers by placing them in the 2nd parameter. Like so:

```
db.survery.update({},{$pull..},{multi:true});
```

If you don't specify a specific document in the first parameter pulling will remove all matching documents, not just a single match.

After running the `$pull` query, i ran the `db.runCommand({getLastError:1})` and it said it nmatched: 2 and I believe its only because `{multi:true}`. There was a match for each document because the first query parameter was left blank, but only the real `$pull` match was modified.

Comment: thanks. But question is regarding "2 records are updated" message, when infact none are updated.

Comment: what's the exact output you get after running the query

db.survey.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { results: { score: 8 , item: "B" } } },
  { multi: true }
)

Comment: "Updated 2 existing record(s)" fyi - using robomongo

Comment: oh ok. I was going to ask what  MongoDB management tool you were using. I haven't used robomongo, why don't you try the same scenario in the standard mongodb javascript shell and see what results you get.

Comment: Qn1 looks like robomongo defect. coz the same query when run from console returned "WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 2, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })"

Comment: Great! For Question one, that may be your answer. I get the same answer when using the simple shell. "nMatched":2 but none modified.